# Qué me está fallando con mi paginador y el <select> para ordenar los resultados de una consulta a MySQL

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una página que muestre algunos artículos (noticias) guardados en una base de datos y que debe permitir al usuario seleccionar el orden en que los artículos aparecen en la página (p. ej. a través de una etiqueta html "select") y además debe tener un paginador. Por separado, he logrado implementar ambas funcionalidades, pero no puedo hacer que funcionen al mismo tiempo. Lo más cercano a lograr lo que busco es lo siguiente: (así como está el código, el usuario puede seleccionar el orden en que los resultados aparecen, pero el paginador falla porque al moverse la primera página, entonces ya no se ven los resultados).

Edito: creo que el problema se debe a que mi script de php solo se ejecuta si (isset($_POST["enviar"])), pero no sé cómo hacer para que el script se ejecute sin tener que enviar el formulario.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/radar.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Header -->
        <header class="header">
            <img class="menu-icon" src="img/menu.png" alt="Menu">
            <img src="img/binario.png" alt="icono">

        </header>``

        <!-- Menú de navegación -->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="index.php">Inicio</a>
            <a href="novedades.php">Novedades</a>
            <a href="prueba.php" class="active">prueba</a>
            <a href="administra/admin.html">Admin</a>
        </nav>

        <!-- Contenido central flexible -->
        <div class="row">

            <aside class="side">
            </aside>


            <section class="content">
                <h2>Novedades</h2>
                <article>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST" name="formulario" onsubmit="return validar()">
                        <select name="orden">
                            <option value="">Ordenar por:</option>
                            <option value="1">Titulo</option>
                            <option value="2">Autor</option>
                            <option value="3">Fecha</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
                    </form>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h3>Articulos</h3>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
                        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bd_top_project');
                        if (!$con) {
                            die('No se pudo realizar la conexion a la base de datos: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                        }
                        mysqli_select_db($con, "bd_top_project");




                        // Recupero el orden seleccionado por el usuario
                        $ord = $_POST["orden"];


                        // Cantidad de registros por página
                        $por_pagina = 1;

                        if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) {
                            $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
                        } else {
                            $pagina = 1;
                        }

                        //la página inicia en 0 y se multiplica por $por_pagina
                        $empieza = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;


                        // Selecciono el orden en que se mostrarán los resultados
                        if ($ord == 1) {
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos ORDER BY titulo LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina";

                            echo "<p>ORDEN titulo<p>";
                        } else if ($ord == 2) {
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos ORDER BY autor LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina";

                            echo "<p>ORDEN autor<p>";
                        } else if ($ord == 3) {
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos ORDER BY fecha LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina";
                            echo "<p>ORDEN fecha<p>";
                        }

                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


                        // Muestros los articulos
                        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<h3>" . $fila["titulo"] . "</h3>";
                            echo "<p>" . $fila["cuerpo"] . "</p>";
                            echo "<p>" . $fila["autor"] . "</p>";
                            echo "<p>" . $fila["fecha"] . "</p>";
                            echo "<img class='imgArticulo' src='administra/" . $fila['imagen'] . "'/>";
                        }

//                        <!--paginador-->
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulos";
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


                        $total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

                        $total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $por_pagina);

                        echo "<center><a class='paginador' href ='prueba.php?pagina=1'>" . 'Primera' . "</a>";

                        $i = 1;
                        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++) {
                            echo "<a class='paginador' href='prueba.php?pagina=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
                        }


                        echo "<a class='paginador' href ='prueba.php?pagina=$total_paginas'>" . 'Última' . "</a></center>";
                        mysqli_close($con);
                    }
                    ?>


                </article>
            </section>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="footer">
        </footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que solo estas enviando la pagina que quieres consultar, pero no estas enviando el ordenamiento que le hiciste, cuando generes el url de paginacion agrega el ordenamiento.

```
echo "<a class='paginador' href='prueba.php?pagina=" . $i . "'&ordenamiento='".$ord."'>" . $i . "</a>";
```

Otra recomendacion, utiliza como delimitador las comillas simples cuando se trate de codigo html, ya que las comillas dobles las puedes encontrar en algunas instrucciones y sera mas engorroso concatenar variables.

Comment: no sé qué pueda estar pasando, pero tampoco me funcionó así :(